# Why did python add 1 at the end? console.log(9.89+3.48) = 13.37000000000001

Tags: python, addition

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AwjX.png

Its adding in 1 at the end of that console log output. Why? 
Answer is suppose to be only 13.37

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s not python, from the look of the screenshot, it’s node js?

Comment: Looks to me like a `float` data type rounding issue.

Comment: Thats correct sir, its javascript. It was a trick question. 
Why does javascript add 1 at the end though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely because it is adding to numbers of type `double` (I am not a huge Python expert though, so I could be wrong). The `double`type, much like `single` does not have perfect precission. Hence some decimal errors can occur...

Comment: In python it's `float` not `double` but the principle is the same :)